# Conditions Within An Insert

Tags: sql

Is it possible to do something like having an `IF` statement within an `INSERT` like so;

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID, NAME, ADDRESS)
VALUES(
    IF CONDITION (SELECT DATA)
    ELSE (SELECT DATA)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of...

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID, NAME, ADDRESS)
SELECT 
CASE condition WHEN result then id else id2 end,
CASE condition WHEN result then name else name2 end,
...
```

or with a `UNION`

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID, NAME, ADDRESS)
SELECT data FROM source WHERE condition
UNION
SELECT data FROM othersource WHERE NOT(condition)
```